How to start "the same desktop" when I connect to Xrdp?
I'm a casual Linux user. I don't fully understand Xsessions and desktop/window manager configs and the like.
I've got a Jetson Nano Mini and I want to setup Xrdp so I can stick it in the cupboard and use it remotely. I've installed Xrdp with sudo apt install xrpd and I can connect and login, but the desktop is not the same as the one you get when you login locally. I realise it's a different Xsession (or at least I think I do) but also the theme and layout are different.
What do I need to do so that the desktop I see when I log in via Xrdp looks the same as the desktop I see when I login locally?
I'm not super fussed about connecting to the console session over RDP, but if that's an easy on/off option in some config somewhere it would be good to know. The Jetson Nano is running Ubuntu 18.04.

What Desktop do you see when you login locally? What Desktop do you see when connecting via xrdp?
